# 3D Physical Compass in Unity (Handling Rotation)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compass

Looking for help towards Rotation in Unity, I have a hand held 3D Compass and I have the hand pointing 'north' which is an empty transform. I'm trying to lock the rotation of the hand so when the compass is tilted, the hand still accurately looks for north.

The problem is, when tilted the hand pops out of the compass.

Here is the following code I have so far and a picture of the issue below.

```
public Transform target;
public Transform housing;
public float speed = 1.0f;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    var lookPos = target.position - transform.position; // assumes this script is attached to the needle
    var housingLocal = housing.InverseTransformPoint(lookPos); // change of coordinates from world space to housing space
    var localProjection = new Vector3(housingLocal.x, 0, housingLocal.z); // Remove the vertical offset so that we will look along the plane of the housing
    var worldProjection = housing.TransformPoint(localProjection); // change of coordinates back into world space

    var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(worldProjection);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime * speed);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The transform of the hand itself is ok? Anyway, I'm going to suposse that the transform.up vector of the hand is aligned with the hand (Just like the primitive of Cylinder in Unity, you can fix this using an empty object as a father).

In that case this code should work:

```
void Update()
{
    Vector3 lookPos = target.position - transform.position;
    transform.up = Vector3.Slerp(transform.up, lookPos, Time.deltaTime * speed);
}
```

With this, the hand of your compass will always be smoothly looking to your point in the north. I recommend you to avoid Quaternions if they are not strictly necessary, I always prefer to rotate through transform ortho vectors (right, up, forward).

Comment: Yes, The hand itself is correctly aligned against the housing. I've also attempted to use empty game objects to offset. This is the code so far updated in the op... @Windgate

Comment: And what's your result with my code? If you could share a screenshot with the hand selected it will be cool